# proper way of AES128Encryption for a password in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I'm facing a problem of password encryption. I'm using AES128 to encrypt the data. Here is the following code:

**LoginController.m**

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>
#import "NSData+AES.h"

- (IBAction)loginButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    NSData *toencrypt = [password.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *credentials = [self md5:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"63jhdf83hf73haf3983f"]]; //returns 679fb1ddf7d81bee0aff2ef251fe6bf5
    NSString *iv = @"kdf67398DF7383fd";
    NSData *data = [toencrypt AES128EncryptWithKey:credentials iv:iv];
    NSString *postdata = [data base64Encoding]; //base64Encoding is implemented in NSData+AES.m
    NSLog(@"Original Password: %@",password);
    NSLog(@"Encrypted Password: %@",postdata);   
}
```

**N.B: md5 conversion and base64Encoding is working fine.

**NSData+AES.m**

```
static char encodingTable[64] =
{
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
    'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
    'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
    'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'
};

@implementation NSData (AES)

- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    int diff = kCCKeySizeAES128 - (dataLength % kCCKeySizeAES128);
    int newSize = 0;

    if(diff > 0){
        newSize = (int)dataLength + diff;
    }

    char dataPtr[newSize];
    memcpy(dataPtr, [self bytes], [self length]);
    for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++){
        dataPtr[i + dataLength] = 0x00;
    }

    size_t bufferSize = newSize + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          0x00, //No padding
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          dataPtr,
                                          sizeof(dataPtr),
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if(cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now If a send **"brad"** it should return **"ur/bq4Rz"**. But unfortunately it returning **"83+eQZW3eI4UWGdNk4nnUw=="**. Whats the problem? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AES 128 is a block cipher with a block size of 16 bytes. So the result is always a multiple of 16 bytes (or 24 bytes in Base 64 encoding). I can't see how a 8 byte long, Base 64 encoded output can possibly be the result of an AES 128 encryption. Why do you think "ur/bq4Rz" is the correct result?

Comment: @Codo: Yes, because in android(java) its generating the right data.

Comment: @Poles. Your other code is just generating what it generates. There is no uniform definition of what is "right data" here. There is no standard way to encode AES-encrypted data. I believe you mean "I want to generate the same thing the Java does, even if it's broken." To that end, you need to start with the Java code and reimplement what it does exactly (or fix the Java code to be more secure).

Comment: @RobNapier: You are right. I don't want to use the broken code. I should do it in iOS way.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this code is pretty insecure. It reuses the same Key+IV for every message, which greatly simplifies the job of decrypting the message for an attacker (especially short messages). And it has  other security problems (poor keyspace, bad padding scheme)

That said, the piece that is specifically broken is that you're passing a 32-byte (256-bit) "key" but you're only using 128-bits of it. You probably meant to use `kCCKeySizeAES256` as the key length. This is unrelated to `kCCAlgorithmAES128` which refers to the block size, not the key length. In the `diff` code, you meant to use `kCCBlockSizeAES128` rather than `kCCKeySizeAES128`, but they are both 16 so it doesn't impact the result.

As @Codo notes, standard CBC mode cannot output cipher text that is not a multiple of 16 bytes in length. Why do you believe "ur/bq4Rz" is the correct encryption? There is a modification of CBC that can do this (it adds what is called "cipher text stealing" or CTS), but this isn't supported by iOS.

Your code is doing zero-padding, which is a very poor way to do it (you're just adding zeros until you get to a 16-byte boundary). The standard (and more secure) solution is PKCS#7 padding, which you're turning off.

If I had to guess, you're copying code that zero-pads the data and then truncates the cipher text to length. The decryption then probably pads the cipher text with zeros and then truncates the garbage at the end (probably based on knowing the length beforehand). I see how this can work, but it's not the normal approach.

If you want an example of how to do this simply, see [Properly Encrypting With AES and CommonCrypto](http://robnapier.net/aes-commoncrypto). If you want a more secure approach that does all of it for you, see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor). Neither of these will generate cipher text that is the same length as your plaintext, however.

Comment: Is there any online tool or code available, so that I can check the encrypted data? 
My encryption process is simple:
**1.** generate **md5** string of credentials string
**2.** encrypt a data(password) with with md5 string and iv string using **AES** encryption.
**3.** encode the data with base64encoding.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: When you say "check the encrypted data," that assumes that the sender and receiver agree on all the parameters, format, key generation, padding, etc. A given key+plaintext should generate different output every time (usually achieved by making the IV random). Testing encryption is extremely difficult ("I can't read it" does not mean it is well encrypted). That is why it's so important to use well-established patterns and not generate your own approach (like using an MD5 string as a key, which is not a good way to do it). RNCryptor is compatible between iOS and Android to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found some issues, for example you don't check if `getCString:maxLength:endocind` failed or not. This is deprecated function and it may fail here, as a result encryption method may use completly different key and IV

Here is my version of this method. This should do the job right:

```
- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    int diff = kCCKeySizeAES128 - (self.length % kCCKeySizeAES128);

    NSMutableData *adjustedData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:self];
    [adjustedData appendData:[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:diff]];

    size_t bufferSize = adjustedData.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                           0x00, //No padding
                                          [key UTF8String], kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          [iv UTF8String],
                                          adjustedData.bytes,
                                          adjustedData.length,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if(cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: will it always return 16 digit long ar according to data?

Comment: that's how it's designed. Input data is extended to the key length (16 bytes of AES key). What you probably need is kind of padding like PKCS#7 padding that can be removed after decryption. I would suggest use kCCOptionPKCS7Padding flag for CCCrypt.